# Elements not staying within their container/overlapping elements

Tags: html, css

my skills are still a novice so this may be a simple issue that I am overlooking but it's doing my head in, please help haha!

The border/items within the "Gaming PC" extend past the container.
I am trying to size all the elements so it's responsive to the user's display size when the website is live.
Up until this point I have used flexbox to create the layout and position things, I am thinking that maybe I should use a combo of the grid for the layout and flex for positioning the items within the defined grid boxes.

All advice is greatly appreciated!
Many thanks.

```css
.PCBUILDS_Main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
}

.PCBContainer {
  height: 100%;
}

#BASICPC,
#WORKSTATIONPC,
#GAMINGPC {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #16cde5;
  font-size: 1.125vw;
}

.GAMINGPCTIER {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 2px groove #16cde5;
  /* margin: 0.5%;
    padding: 2%;  */
}

.GAMINGPCTIER>h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.095vw;
}

.GAMINGPCTIER>h2:hover {
  background-color: #16cde5;
}

.PCTIERSPECSINFO {
  border: 2px groove #16cde5;
  /* margin: 0.5%; */
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.PCTIERSPECSINFO>div {
  position: absolute;
}


/* Position stack order */

#p1 {
  height: 49.5%;
  width: 29%;
  background-color: #181310;
  z-index: 4;
}

#list1080p,
li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#p2 {
  height: 49.5%;
  width: 29%;
  background-color: #181310;
  z-index: 3;
}

#p3 {
  height: 49.5%;
  width: 29%;
  background-color: #181310;
  z-index: 2;
}

#p4 {
  height: 49.5%;
  width: 29%;
  background-color: #181310;
  z-index: 1;
}

#p5 {
  height: 49.5%;
  width: 29%;
  background-color: #181310;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* PC Builds Brief Description */

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #16cde5;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #EE0055;
}

.description-bolder {
  color: #16cde5;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #EE0055;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
}

#basicpcbox,
#workstationbox,
#gamingpcbox {
  border: 1px solid #1ea6ac;
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
}

#gamingpcbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: space-around;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Border Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="BasicWebsite2.css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="HeadBox">
      <a href="Homepage.html">Homepage</a>
      <a href="About_Us.html">About Us</a>
      <a href="PC_Builds.html">PC Builds</a>
      <a href="Technical_Assistance.html">Technical Assistance</a>
      <a href="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="Gallery">Gallery</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="PCBUILDS_Main">
    <div class="PCBUILDSBORDER" id="BASICPC">
      <div class="PCBContainer" id="BASICPCBContainer">
        <h1>The Basic<br> PC</h1>
        <div id="basicpcbox">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PCBUILDSBORDER" id="GAMINGPC">
      <div class="PCBContainer" id="GAMINGPCBContainer">
        <h1>The Gaming<br> PC</h1>
        <div id="gamingpcbox">
          <div class="GAMINGPCTIER">
            <h2 onclick="focusp1()">The Retro<br> PC</h2>
            <h2 onclick="focusp2()">The 1080p<br> PC</h2>
            <h2 onclick="focusp3()">The 2k<br> PC</h2>
            <h2 onclick="focusp4()">The 4k<br> PC</h2>
            <h2 onclick="focusp5()">The Overkill<br> PC</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="PCTIERSPECSINFO">
            <div id="p1">
              <section id="sp1" class="position">
                <h3>Retro</h3>
                <p><span class="description-bolder">The Retro PC</span> is perfect for the old school gamer, as well as basic document applications, web browsing, media viewing and basic graphic design.
                </p>
                <ul id="listretro">
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">GPU:</span> *CPU has Onboard Graphics* </li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">CPU:</span> 5600G 6 Core 4.4GHZ</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RAM:</span> 8GB DDR4</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">SSD:</span> 500GB M.2 Nvme SSD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">HDD:</span> *Optional* 1TB HDD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Motherboard:</span> 64GB RAM Capacity, 2 - 4 SATA Ports</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Case:</span> Solid/Mini</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Cooling:</span> Fans</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RGB:</span> *Optional*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">PSU:</span> 500w Gold PSU</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
            </div>
            <div id="p2">
              <section id="sp2" class="position">
                <h3>1080p</h3>
                <p><span class="description-bolder">The 1080p PC</span> is a great <span class="description-bolder">beginner bundle</span> for the avid gamer and small scale video editing, this build is <span class="description-bolder">upgradeable</span>                  for a more powerful desktop gaming experience!
                </p>
                <ul id="list1080p">
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">GPU:</span> GTX 1650 4GB DDR6 </li>
                  <!-- $129 -->
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">CPU:</span> AMD Ryzen 5 5600</li>
                  <!-- $249-->
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RAM:</span> 16GB DDR4</li>
                  <!-- $120-->
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">SSD:</span> 500GB m.2 Nvme SSD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">HDD:</span> *Optional* 1TB HDD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Motherboard:</span> 64GB RAM Capacity*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Case:</span> Solid/Visible-Interior</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Cooling:</span> 4 Case Fans + CPU Fan</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RGB:</span> *Optional*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">PSU:</span> 550w Gold PSU</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
            </div>
            <div id="p3">
              <section id="sp3" class="position">
                <h3>2k</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa vitae obcaecati suscipit unde soluta quo beatae atque sit enim eaque. Eum, commodi debitis? Tenetur necessitatibus magnam cumque, tempora suscipit quae?
                </p>
                <ul id="list2k">
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">GPU:</span> RTX 3050</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">CPU:</span> AMD Ryzen 5 5600X</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RAM:</span> 32GB DDR4</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">SSD:</span> 500GB m.2 Nvme SSD + 1TB m.2 Nvme SSD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">HDD:</span> *Optional*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Motherboard:</span> 64GB RAM Capacity*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Case:</span> Solid/Visible-Interior</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Cooling:</span> AIO Liquid Cooling</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RGB:</span> *Optional*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">PSU:</span> 650w Gold PSU</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
            </div>
            <div id="p4">
              <section id="sp4" class="position">
                <h3>4k</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa vitae obcaecati suscipit unde soluta quo beatae atque sit enim eaque. Eum, commodi debitis? Tenetur necessitatibus magnam cumque, tempora suscipit quae?</p>
                <ul id="list4k">
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">GPU:</span> RTX 3080</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">CPU:</span> AMD 7 5800X</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RAM:</span> 64GB DDR4</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">SSD:</span> 1TB M.2 Nvme SSD + 4TB M.2 Nvme SSD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">HDD:</span> *Optional*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Motherboard:</span> 128GB RAM Capacity, 6 - 8 SATA Ports</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Case:</span> Visible-Interior</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Cooling:</span> AIO Liquid Cooling</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RGB:</span> RAM, Cooler, Case Fans</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">PSU:</span> 750w Gold PSU</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
            </div>
            <div id="p5">
              <section id="sp5" class="position">
                <h3>Overkill</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa vitae obcaecati suscipit unde soluta quo beatae atque sit enim eaque. Eum, commodi debitis? Tenetur necessitatibus magnam cumque, tempora suscipit quae?</p>
                <ul id="listOverkill">
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">GPU:</span> RTX 3090ti</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">CPU:</span> AMD 7 5950X</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RAM:</span> 256GB DDR4</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">SSD:</span> 4TB M.2 Nvme SSD + 10TB m.2 Nvme SSD</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">HDD:</span> *Optional*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Motherboard:</span> 256GB RAM Capacity, 8 - 10 SATA Ports</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Case:</span> Visible-Interior</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">Cooling:</span> AIO Liquiq Cooling/*Custom Water Cooling*</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">RGB:</span> RAM, Cooler, Case Fans, Cables, Case</li>
                  <li><span class="description-bolder">PSU:</span> 1000w Gold PSU</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PCBUILDSBORDER" id="WORKSTATIONPC">
      <div class="PCBContainer" id="WORKSTATIONPCBContainer">
        <h1>The Workstation<br> PC</h1>
        <div id="workstationbox"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer id="BottomElement">
    <div id="FootBox">
      <h3>ABN: XXXXXXXXX</h3>
      <h3>Email: LocalPCBuilds@outlook.com</h3>
      <h3>Ph: +61417133559</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: You just need to add `overflow: auto` or any other value based on your need to `PCBUILDSBORDER` class.

Comment: It looks like this solved the issue:
#basicpcbox, #workstationbox, #gamingpcbox {
    border: 1px solid #1ea6ac;
    height: 80%;    /*  this was 95%  */
    width: 100%;
  }

/* I had not yet defined a height for the h1 element on top*/

  .PCBContainer > h1 {
    height: 20%;
    margin: 0;
  }